# ASP.NET - No Datakey on Gridview RowDeleting event!

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, ado.net, datatable

I have a GridView just like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwStudents" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    ShowHeader="False" onrowdeleting="gvwStudents_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="Remove" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is how I am creating my DataTable, which the GridView is bound to, so that you know what data I am dealing with:

```
private DataTable MakeStudentsTable()
{
    DataTable students = new DataTable();

    DataColumn ID = students.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    ID.AutoIncrement = true;

    DataColumn firstName = students.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    DataColumn lastName = students.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    DataColumn email = students.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));


    return students;
}
```

Why, oh, why are there no keys passed in the EventArgs of the RowDeleting event? I need to remove the record from the ADO.NET DataTable that I am keeping in session state when this event is fired.

Why isn't this working? Is it that DataKeys only work when using a DataSource control?

Comment: I think you should add the "databinding" tag to this question.

BTW, I've been banging my head over exactly the same problem.

Comment: How are you adding students to your table?  Is the data being populated in your table before the Deleting method is called (i.e. in Page_Load)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
private DataTable MakeStudentsTable()
{
    DataTable students = new DataTable();

    DataColumn ID = students.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    ID.AutoIncrement = true;

    DataColumn firstName = students.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    DataColumn lastName = students.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    DataColumn email = students.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));

    DataRow student = students.NewRow();
    student["FirstName"] = "foo";
    student["LastName"] = "bar";
    student["Email"] = "foo@bar.com";
    students.Rows.Add(student);

    return students;
}

protected void gvwStudents_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string id = this.gvwStudents.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();   
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to access in the event args?

Comment: Your assertion is correct, GridViewDeletedEventArgs.Keys collection is only populated when using a DataSourceID.

Comment: This is a workaround to the problem that GridViewDeletedEventArks.Keys collection isn't populated.
Are we just giving up on ever having this populated?

Answer (score 1):

Set the DataKeyNames Property of the GridView control to the name(s) of the primary key(s) of your data.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
```

and see if the field even has a value.

Comment: I have checked this. It does have a value.